# How can I constrain or choose between one or other foreign key?

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, foreign-keys

The problem is conceptual (databases relationships), so the language isn't the focus here, but I'm using Python and Django.

I have 3 models/tables:

- Company
- Customer
- Address

Eg.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example

class Adress(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    state = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    
    # here I want the address owner
    # I could put something like this:
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I want the address to belong to the customer or the company, but not both.
I know that I can simply create 2 Address classes, eg, CustomerAddress, CompanyAddress, each one with its correct foreign key:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example

class CompanyAdress(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    state = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class CustomerAdress(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    state = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) #example
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

But I don't want to for two reasons:

1. The duplicated code and the fact that in Django admin panel I will have two separated address lists, which doesn't makes much sense, since all address are structurally identical. I can fix the duplicated code creating a base class, inheriting from it and etc., but I still will have 2 lists in admin panel.
2. I can have, in the future, the same conceptual problem, but with more complexity, e.g. 300 classes of some things and 1 class that should have a foreign key for only one of the 300.

What should I do?

Comment: Why don't you just add a foreign key `address` field in the Company and Customer's models?

Comment: Search for `party model`. Common pattern. Or super-type, sub-type
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a196713%20subtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an UML diagram take a look at Martin Fowler's [Analysis Patterns](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/apchap2.pdf). The following is a DB model.

```
-- Address ADR exists.
--
address {ADR}
     PK {ADR}
```

*`Party` is a generic term for a person or an organization; discriminator `TYP` is used to distinguish between the two.*

```
-- Party PTY, of party-type TYP, resides at address ADR.
--
party {PTY, TYP, ADR}
   PK {PTY}
   SK {PTY, TYP}

CHECK TYP in {'P', 'O'}

FK {ADR} REFERENCES address {ADR}
```

```
-- Person, a party PTY of party-type TYP = 'P', exists.
--
person {PTY, TYP}
    PK {PTY}

CHECK TYP = 'P'

FK {PTY, TYP} REFERENCES party {PTY, TYP}
```

```
-- Organization, a party PTY of party-type TYP = 'O', exists.
--
organization {PTY, TYP}
          PK {PTY}

CHECK TYP = 'O'

FK {PTY, TYP} REFERENCES party {PTY, TYP}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL


PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

A word about *subtypes*. The proper way to implement constraints for subtypes would be to use assertions (`CREATE ASSERTION`), but it is still not available in major DBs. I am using `FKs` instead, and as all other substitute methods it is not perfect. People argue a lot,  on SO and SE-DBA, what is better. I encourage you to check other methods too.

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the Foreign key as null=True and control the input in the database through views as needed:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_lenght=100) 
    state = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Comment: Correct answer that I thought 